# How to extract distinct from a bag of tuples?

Tags: apache-pig

so i have the following data structure in pig after description:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| summed_hours_and_miles_by_driver     | group:int     | :bag{:tuple(driver_name:chararray)}             | total_hours:long     | total_miles:long     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                      | 27            | {(Mark Lochbihler), ..., (Mark Lochbihler)}     | 220                  | 11006                | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The idea is that driver name(Mark Lochbihler) is replicated multiple times in a bag of tuples.
How can i restrict it to a single name there something like DISTINCT in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Distinct](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/Distinct.html), assuming A is your relation something like this

```
summed_hours_and_miles_by_driver = FOREACH grp GENERATE 
                                       group,
                                       org.apache.pig.builtin.Distinct(A.driver_name),
                                       total_hours,
                                       total_miles;
```